# Does the term "abusive" connote intent?

Tags: connotation

When applied to an individual, does the term "abusive" imply that the individual harbors malicious intent?

Similarly, if applied to an action, does "abusive" infer that the individual who performed it had unsavory intentions?

Comment: I can't see how someone could be *abusive* unintentionally. I could see someone being *neglectful* unintentionally, in that *neglect* is passive; but *abuse* is active.

Comment: @DanBron It is active, yes … but whether the person who does it really has _malicious intent_ is a deeper, more psychological question. I would venture that most people we would label abusers do not see themselves as such, and would say (quite honestly, to their knowledge) that they have no malicious intent behind their actions. It’s similar to alcoholism and other such plagues: there’s a kind of creeping denial that drives it. Can you really call it _intent_ when you’re so deep in denial you don’t even see there’s something wrong? Volition in the act, certainly; intent behind it … perhaps?

Comment: Janus, whether or not the abuser believes he is committing evil is orthogonal to the question of whether his behavior is intentional. If a man strikes his wife, he is being *abusive*, whether or not he believes he's doing it for her own good, in order to "correct" some behavior he thinks is detrimental to her.  By a similar chain of logic, someone can "*abuse*" alcohol, even while thinking everything's fine; it's a matter of how much he drinks, not whether he thinks he drinks too much.

Comment: @medica, I have no such credentials, and certainly am in no position to disagree with any of your statements. What I'm trying to say is not that the abuser must recognize his abuse; only that (a) we *agree the behavior is abusive* in some objective sense, and (b) the abuser *committed the act intentionally*. If those two things are true, then we can objectively say, abuse must be intentional.

Comment: @DanBron - I agree with you from an outside perspective (see my answer). The problem is with the way the question was asked.

Comment: How is this relevant to ELU? Isn't this more medical/psychological/legal than something that can be answered authoritatively for normal English usage?

Comment: @SrJoven, I am inquiring about the normal English usage.  I'm sure you can tell from my question, that language is not my specialty. My elementary school child had a fairly innocuous incident at school where he punched a friend to get his attention. Of course, a form came home for us to sign.  And, even though it was written that his intention was to get the attention of his friend, the term "abusive behavior" was selected in a dropdown box on the same form.  I thought that sounded extreme.

Comment: I understand your feelings on this issue. A dictionary answer or grammar answer may not necessarily be effective in providing a definition in the framework that you've encountered, though. Whether an answer complies with your views on the subject or not, the form reports observed behavior, not necessarily intent.

Comment: If I might dehumanize things a bit:  One could have a handsaw of the type that is intended for wood and then ignorantly attempt to saw metal with it, thereby abusing the saw.

Answer (score 3):

This question simplifies a complicated issue. To normal people outside of a situation looking in, yes, of course all abuse looks like it comes from malevolent intent. If people could be completely honest with themselves, then they too would would see malevolent intent.

So, as Josh correctly answered, yes, there is ill-intent behind all abuse.

But your question is *does the term "abusive" imply that the individual harbors malicious intent?*

The answer is not always, because individuals don't all have the advantage of wisdom and clear perspective from which to judge their motives.

Comment: +1: Also, it's fairly common (though certainly not universal or excusable) for people to only be abusive when under stress, or drunk, or in other scenarios where their ability to consciously form intent is impaired.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions given below imply strong actions which tend to break rules and laws. I'd say that in performing them you are very likely to be supposed of being aware of what you are doing.

[Abusive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Abusive):

> - Characterized by improper or wrongful use: abusive utilization of public funds.
> - Using or containing insulting or coarse language: finally reprimanded the abusive colleague.
> - Causing physical injury to another: abusive punishment.
> - Relating to or practicing sexual abuse.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

This is, or can be, an extraordinarily difficult subject, in part because of the varying definitions of "abuse" which people use.

If "abuse" is simply the use of violence towards those around you (particularly spouse and children), there are any number of justifications.

From the Bible: "Spare the rod and spoil the child".

From the Koran: "Men are the maintainers of women because Allah has made some of them to excel others and because they spend out of their property; the good women are therefore obedient, guarding the unseen as Allah has guarded; and (as to) those on whose part you fear desertion, admonish them, and leave them alone in the sleeping-places and beat them; then if they obey you, do not seek a way against them; surely Allah is High, Great."

From "A Boy Named Sue":

"Son, this world is rough

And if a man's gonna make it, he's gotta be tough

And I knew I wouldn't be there to help ya along.

So I give ya that name and I said goodbye

I knew you'd have to get tough or die

And it's the name that helped to make you strong."

And, on an even less savory note, from "The Little Green Book", by the Ayatollah Khomeini: "If a man who has married a girl who has not reached puberty possesses her sexually before her ninth birthday, inflicting traumatisms upon her, he has no right to repeat such an act upon her." Note that the limitation is lifted upon her ninth birthday.

So the question becomes, if an abuser claims to believe that he or she is acting in a way which is religiously required/permitted or better in the long run for the abused, do you accept the explanation? It's certainly true than people lie about their motivations, but do they always do so? Is "This hurts me more than it does you" always a lie? Is such an explanation always transparent rationalization which serves to cover the knowledge of guilt?

Given the diversity of people's actions and motivations, I'm inclined to accept that sometimes the justification is sincere. Note that this in no way suggests that I accept such beliefs as true - only that I believe that the speaker may honestly do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how just hitting your wife or husband equals abuse. The way I see it, abuse is just physical violence that has been taken to a certain degree. You can't just say that if you strike your spouse once, it's abuse. Also, I say abuse isn't just so much the action but also the intent, depending on you definition of abuse.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, @Jason. Quite a few people would consider striking your spouse the ***certain degree*** that carries an interaction over the line into abuse. It would probably be good to rise above you own opinion and offer some supporting evidence.